# Anyone consider placing public class members alphabetically?

Tags: coding-style, standards

Considering that API docs are often in alphabetical order, perhaps it would make sense to arrange public class members alphabetically, with their exclusive private member dependencies interspersed between each public method. And general private members arranged separately alphabetically or by context.

Not really considering conforming to this but was curious if anyone does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally organise my public methods by functionality, but off the top of my head one popular open source library that (sort of) follow an alphabetized structure is CodeIgniter.

For example their [CI_Javascript](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Javascript.php) class groups methods by functionality (events, effects), and each group is organised alphabetically. But they do seem to break the alphabetical rule sometimes, which kind of defeats the purpose.